# How to monitor SMS being sent by apps?

Tags: sms, privacy, logging

I just found from my mobile bill that SMS is being sent out to some 4 digit number (permium number) from my mobile. I could not find the message in my SMS app - "Messages".

I checked with the telecom company and confirmed that it's not some service I subscribed to.

I did see the same issue on an acquaintance phone which was by Huawei sending this SMS every week.

Mine phone is from LG and I have being using it for over 3 years and this is the first time. I don't remember installing any new app. Not sure what changed in the phone.

I am assuming that one of the apps on my phone is sending some kind of log. I don't remember any app asking for permission.

How can I find out what was the content of the message sent? Not sure which app is sending it.

What is this type of SMS that the apps are sending? Anyway to block it?

In the setting: app permission>SMS permissions: (apps with SMS permission)

- Contacts
- Google
- Google Play services
- Google Play Store
- Messages (Google app that I am using)
- Messaging (LG default SMS app)

Comment: If two different phone are affected may be the phone is not the culprit. The network operator networks are all interconnected and using the SS7 protocol other people can do a lot you would not expect. Therefore I would recommend to power off your device over night and on the next bill check the send date and time of every unwanted SMS. If the time is during a phase where you have powered down your device the device can't be the problem.

Comment: My phone is off daily (its a routine from long back) between 10pm & 7:30 am. The message was sent at 10 am.

Comment: I too suspected the network operator and still do based on their general things. I have a sim from the same operator in an iPhone and that never has the same issue.